# Can you edit partitions on a disk image?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, operating-systems, windows-installation, disk-image

I partitioned my hard drive into three partitions of various sizes. Then I installed Windows 7 Ultimate and went through the standard series software installations and updates. I used the Windows 7 disk imaging utility once I had everything the way I want it. Then I realized I had installed Windows it on the wrong partition!!! The partition I installed it on was too small and I have run out of space.

Can I somehow use the imaging utility to avoid spending all that time installing/updating and yet end up with a bigger partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can shrink the volume from which you want to exclude the space then download [Easeus Partition magic home edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm) which is free and then try the merge option available there. You can also use the `resize/move partition` option to resize the partition. See [how to merge a partition using easeus](http://www.partition-tool.com/download/docs/merge_partitions.swf).

Comment: I'm assuming this won't work for me, for the same reason as the Windows Disk Management solution proposed by WikiWitz.

Comment: I have used it and its perfect to do that. You have not to assume just give a try to it.

Comment: Hmm. I will give this a try.

Comment: WOOHOO!!! It worked!!! I changed my partition size from 25 GB to 75 GB and moved it to the front of the HDD. (I didn't have any data on the drive other than on the 25 GB partition.)

Comment: Glad thaat it helped out.

Answer (score 1):

Hit the Windows Key then right-click on Computer and click Manage. 
Go to Storage > Disk Management > Right-click the desired partition > Select Extend Volume...

[image]

You may need to shrink the other partitions to free disk space for extending.

Comment: Using Windows disk management you can only extend a volume to a unallocated volume to the right of it, he will need 3rd party partitioning software to allocate freespace from another existing partition.

Comment: This would have been perfect, but the partition I want to extend is all the way to the right. :(